# MYSQL - WHERE condition not working in Query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a simple password recovery form where user will enter their date of birth for verification and then it will proceed to change password if not it will prompt the user that their date of birth does not match.

**Problem:** Query not working with multiple AND conditions

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

    $submit = $_POST['next'];
    $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
    $dob2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob2']);
    $dob3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob3']);

    if($submit) {
     $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
     mysql_select_db("logindb");
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE dob='$dob' AND dob2='$dob2' AND dob3='$dob3'");
     $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if($numrows!=0) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $dbdob = $row['dob'];
        $dbdob2 = $row['dob2'];
        $dbdob3 = $row['dob3'];
      }
     //check to see if they match
     if($dob==$dbdob&&$dob2==$dbdob2&&$dob3==$dbdob3) {
      echo "Password Reset Page";
      die();
     }
     else
     {
      echo "Invalid Date of Birth";
      die();
     }
    }
    else
     {
      echo "Data does not Match";
      die();
     }
    }
    ?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="PasswordReset.php" method="POST" name="passwordreset">
    <select name="dob" required id="dob">
        <option disabled>Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dob2" required id="dob2">
        <option disabled>Month</option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">November</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dob3" required id="dob3">
        <option disabled>Year</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1969">1969</option>
        <option value="1968">1968</option>
        <option value="1967">1967</option>
        <option value="1966">1966</option>
        <option value="1965">1965</option>
        <option value="1964">1964</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>
        <option value="1962">1962</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1958">1958</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1956">1956</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1954">1954</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1952">1952</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1950">1950</option>
        <option value="1949">1949</option>
        <option value="1948">1948</option>
        <option value="1947">1947</option>
        <option value="1946">1946</option>
        <option value="1945">1945</option>
        <option value="1944">1944</option>
        <option value="1943">1943</option>
        <option value="1942">1942</option>
        <option value="1941">1941</option>
        <option value="1940">1940</option>
        <option value="1939">1939</option>
        <option value="1938">1938</option>
        <option value="1937">1937</option>
        <option value="1936">1936</option>
        <option value="1935">1935</option>
        <option value="1934">1934</option>
        <option value="1933">1933</option>
        <option value="1932">1932</option>
        <option value="1931">1931</option>
        <option value="1930">1930</option>
        <option value="1929">1929</option>
        <option value="1928">1928</option>
        <option value="1927">1927</option>
        <option value="1926">1926</option>
        <option value="1925">1925</option>
        <option value="1924">1924</option>
        <option value="1923">1923</option>
        <option value="1922">1922</option>
        <option value="1921">1921</option>
        <option value="1920">1920</option>
        <option value="1919">1919</option>
        <option value="1918">1918</option>
        <option value="1917">1917</option>
        <option value="1916">1916</option>
        <option value="1915">1915</option>
        <option value="1914">1914</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Please note that using `mysql_real_escape_string` will **not** protect against SQL-injections! See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/2344584) for instance. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Are you really storing year, month, day in separate fields rather than using a single date field in your database?

Comment: ya i get this inspiration from appleid registration form

Comment: Why still using the depreciated mysql switch to mysqli.

Comment: The form !== the database; it would be more sensible to use a `date` datatype column on the database, because you're storing an actual date, not simply a set of numbers and strings

Comment: Not working is not an error,what exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is if i disabled(remove) the $dob3 from the php code it works but after adding back the $dob3 it does not work anymore

Comment: Try to verify the POST with isset. Probably dob3 is empty so the query doesnt find anything.

Comment: still does not work, I get echo "Data does not match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select db is wrong:(**Note** dont use mysql use mysqli)

**change this line:**

```
 mysql_select_db("logindb");
```

To

```
  mysql_select_db("logindb",$connect);
```

Comment: no need to specify connection it's only optional if not specified the last open connection will be used.Check the php docs http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: @user1613360 where he open previous connection?